# If Database password is encoded how to compare oldpassword and new password in spring mvc

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc

If Database password is encoded how to compare oldpassword and new password in spring mvc

Suppose in user send the request new password anoj and old password is anoj how to compare because db password is encoded

```
if(passwordForm.getPassword().equals(userDto.getPassword())) {
    bindingResult.rejectValue("reject", "reject");
}
```

here `userDTO.getPassword` value is encoded`and`passwordFormCommand.getPassword()`is`anoj` then how to compare

It was encoded like this

```
user = new User().setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()))
```

Comment: An answer would depend on knowing "How it was encoded" in the first place

Comment: Again, How did you HASH/Encode the Plain Text Password when you stored it on the database?

Comment: Encode the new password using the same rules and compare the encoded passwords

Comment: user = new User()
                                     .setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()))

Comment: That hash looks a bit odd, it does not seem to conform to the bcrypt format?